# CakePHP unit-testing controllers with explicit joins

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

The controller code I'm looking to test includes functions where queries like

```
$this->Model->find('all', [
    'joins' => [
        'table' => database.table,
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => ['table.id' => 'Model.table_id']
    ],
]);
```

are used extensively.

The problem is that `testAction` correctly finds the Model's table in the `test` datasource, but does not modify the explicit join, which joins it to the actual `database.table`, rather than `test.table`.

My intuition tells me that re-writing these queries to use CakePHP's contain rather than join should allow CakePHP's `ControllerTestCase` to replace the joined model's datasource with the `test` datasource, fixing the issue. However, I'd prefer not to rewrite all the query code.

Does anyone know a way to work around this? If not, am I correct in thinking that the contain method would fix solve the problem?

Comment: Well, the database is--yes, explicitly--specified because the tables are actually in different databases--hence the problem. I found an extraordinarily hack-y method to get the tests to run as desired but it looks as though the queries will have to be written cake-style for proper testing.

Comment: Something like `$this->Model->getDataSource['config']['database']`? Would the test case correctly change that to the `test` datasource?

Comment: or rather `$this->Model->getDataSource()->config['database']`, which appears to work. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the join, `'table' => database.table,` is hard-coded, so cake cannot redirect the query to the `test` datasource (it will look for `table` in `database`). To fix this, replace `database` in `database.test` with `$this->Model->getDataSource()->config['database']`, where `Model` refers to the model `table` represents (or is a join table for). In test cases, Cake can change models' datasources to the `test` datasource, so the query will be properly modified.